# Doubling generic array's size with bit shifters in java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, bit-manipulation

I am trying to double up my generic array's size if it has reached my `maxCapacity` value. Of course that I could do that by just multiplying my `maxCapacity * 2` and that will make me able to append twice as many values. The thing is that I saw that somehow using bit shifters you could achieve the same thing. It has to do with the operators `=<<` or `=>>` or something like that.

Here's my code:

```
....
private E [ ] list;
private int maxCapacity, currentSize;
....

maxCapacity = 10;
currentSize = 0;

if(currentSize > maxCapacity)
    maxCapacity *= 2;
...
```

My maxCapacity is not the actual size of the array but in my methods I make sure that when inserting objects to my array, it won't go further than the `maxCapacity` value.

Do you know how to achieve the same behavior but using the bit shift operators on the fly? I don't know if this is even possible but I remember looking at some code a while ago that adopted this behavior.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you want to double your maxCapacity its equivalent to shift one bit to the left using << operator. This will add zeroes and, therefore, multiplying by 2. In your case, you should do: maxCapacity << 1

Comment: Just curious why you want to implement your own version of `ArrayList` when you can just use what's already there. Also, even if `maxCapacity <<= 1` works, IMHO you shouldn't use it here. It is less clear, and even in `C` I suspect that any compiler developped in this century will produce the same code for both versions. (It used to make a difference some decades ago before we had optimizing compilers.)

Comment: This is the least useful use of bitwise operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have to do:

```
if (currentSize > maxCapacity) 
    maxCapacity <<= 1;
```

Shifting to the left with `1` will double the value of `maxCapacity`.

For example, if `maxCapacity` is `5`, it will be `101` in its binary representation. Shifting with `1` would mean to append a single `0` to the binary representation, which would make it `1010`. This now represents `10`.

Comment: Ofcourse the idea is correct but i guess you can't simply use the signed shift like that... you have to change the syntax.